# Translate pdf which has mix of English and other languages

Tags: python, pdf, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to use google translate api.  I could translate a pdf which is purely Chinese or Korean into English language,  but am not able to translate a pdf which starts in English and continues in Korean.  It detects the source language as English and does not translate the Korean part.
Have given a sample of the document below.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far?